# java extended class inheritance

Tags: java, subclass

```
Sum s = new Sum();
Sum.SetToZero z = new Sum.SetToZero();

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String read = input.nextLine();

while (!read.equals("end")) {

    if (read.equals("add")) {
        s.add()
    } 
    else if (read.equals("get")) {
        System.out.println(s.returnTotal());
    }
    else if (read.equals("zero")) {
        z.zero();
    }

   read = input.nextLine();
}
```

class:

```
public class Sum {

    int total = 0;

    public void add() {
        total += 1;
    }

    public int returnTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public static class SetToZero extends Sum {

        public void  zero() {
            total = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

input:

```
add
add
zero
add
get
add
get
end
```

output:

```
3
4
```

output wanted:

```
1
2
```

Shouldn't the subclass inherit the total and set it to zero? What am I doing wrong? I know I could just move the `zero` into the main class but I want it to be in a separate class. thx for your help.

Comment: Can you show your `main` method? Without a `main` method, your program doesn't do anything.

Comment: Along with the main also add the subclass you are referring to

Comment: Do you use the same instance of `sum` and `setToZero`?

Comment: `System.out.println(s.get());` where is `get` defined?  This example snippet does not seem to match your other code.  *Complete* code please, not this half stuff.

Comment: Please respect the Java naming conventions and do not start your class name with a lowercase letter.

Comment: `else if (read.equals("zero")) { z.zero();` This is a completely separate object from `s`.  Of course it does not affect the other object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making your `total` variable `static`, you can get the desired output.

```
class Sum {
    static int total = 0;
    public void add() {
        total += 1;
    }

    public int returnTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public static class SetToZero extends Sum {
        public void  zero() {
            total = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from things pointed out in names like not using lowecase letters to start your class name; I think the reason why it's not working is because you're using two different variable instances for `Sum` and `Sum.SetToZero`. You don't need to create a new variables since `SetToZero` has all the attributes of `Sum`. I think you should change this:

```java
Sum s = new Sum();
Sum.SetToZero z = new Sum.SetToZero();
```

```java
Sum.SetToZero s = new Sum.SetToZero(); // use s for all operations
```

Here is how your modified main method would look:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sum.SetToZero s = new Sum.SetToZero();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String read = input.nextLine();

    while (!read.equals("end")) {

        if (read.equals("add")) {
            s.add();
        } 
        else if (read.equals("get")) {
            System.out.println(s.get());
        }
        else if (read.equals("zero")) {
            s.zero();
        }

        read = input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

When I ran this, I saw expected output:

```
src : $ java Sum
add
add
zero
add
get
1
add
get
2
end
```